# Reassign value of variable

Tags: c#

I'm using C# and reading a line of text (ln) and assigning an image to a picture box.  After the image is selected, I check to see if it's night or day and attempt to change the selected image to the night version if the sun has gone done.

```
        charPos = ln.IndexOf("partly cloudy", 0);
        if (charPos > -1)
        {
            skyimg = "sct.jpg";
            skymsg = "Partly Cloudy";
            If (AMPM = "P") skyimg = "nsct.jpg";
        }
```

The compiler tells me I'm missing a semi-colon and just doesn't like that second "if" check.
Do I have to use an "else if" and include both possible conditions in each check?

Answer (score 5):

C# is case-sensitive. It should be `if` rather than `If`. And you also mean to write `==` rather than `=` for the equality test.

```
if (AMPM == "P") skyimg = "nsct.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

You capitalised `If`. The compiler thinks `If` is a variable identifier (and therefore an expression) not the reserved keyword `if`, which is what you wanted. To fix your problem, make it the lower case `if`.

If we run with the logic, it is trying to build a statement with what you typed, but what you wrote isn't valid syntax. If you put a semicolon after the `If`, it would be a correct expression (assuming that `If` was a valid identifier e.g. a variable name). After that you would get an error saying that `If` isn't defined.